# [LUA ]Making a random song picker

Tags: lua

Been trying to get a random song "I'm using fruit placeholders for now" and it always returns Orange
and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local songLists = {"Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"}
local songValue = math.random(#songLists)
local songSelected = songLists[songValue]

print(tostring(songSelected))
```

Comment: I replicated your code on my machine and it worked, that is, it produced random values rather than `"Orange"` every time. For clarification, what version of Lua are you using and what operating system are you using?

Comment: lua 5.1.4-46, and I'm running windows 10

Comment: I reproduced your code on a Linux 18.04 virtual machine with Lua 5.3 and I got the expected random result. As far as I can tell, you code should work: you are seeding the random number generator, and accessing a random value within your table. Maybe check out the Lua 5.1 reference manual for more details on `math.random`.

Answer (score 0):

Lua uses PRNG (pseudorandom number generator) to calculate random number.

`math.randomseed(os.time())` initalizes formula with some sort of data current time (not the best decision). `os.time()` gives current time with prezision of 1s, it means if you execute this code in loop within part of second you will get the same seed number (if clock not changes). The best practice is to initialize random `math.randomseed(...)` once application is started and with better random data as process id, os.clock(), ...

Most likely your problem is `math.randomseed(...)` is executed many times with the same seed data in this code or may be in anothe part of application.